# jQuery - Using javascript variable elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, declaration

I fear this question may be extremely newbie level, but I am just drawing a blank.

Within the `$(document).ready` function I have some DatePicker code...

```
$('#date-view1').datePicker({
    selectWeek: true,
    inline: true,
    startDate: '01/01/1996'
}).bind('dateSelected', function (e, selectedDate, $td) {
    $('#date1').val(selectedDate.asString());
    var pfb = selectedDate.asString();
});
```

The part I am struggling with is the `var pfb = selectedDate.asString();`

I want to use the variable `pfb` further down my page in a different function called `showProjects()`.

How can I do this? I have tried declaring the variable inside and outside of the `$(document).ready` function without luck.

Thanks

Comment: What do you plan to do with pfb later on?  Just curious, might help us suggest another option besides the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `var pfb` before your document ready block. That'll make it available elsewhere on the page. In the document ready you'll be SETTING an already DECLARED variable.

Comment: Dan, I have tried var pfb = ''; AND var pfb = ""; AND just var pfb; Then in the DatePicker code I declare pfb = selectedDate.asString();
 without the var. Then I set an ALERT for testing and it comes up empty.

Comment: But are you declaring var pfb outside the document ready block? If you want it to be global, you have to declare it at global scope.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use global variables to store values which are accessible from anywhere in the page. Of the many ways of doing this is
setting the value using  `window.pfb = selectedDate.asString();`
and accessing it later anywhere with `window.pfb`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a problem area, but I wouldn't have tried passing pfb as a param in that onclick event - I think that may re-initialise pfb, or create a new var.

If you're creating it globally (not ideal but should work) then you shouldn't need to pass pfb as a param anyway.

Also, it's good practice not to attach events on the elements like that. Ideally - and jQuery makes this very easy - you should have something in your $(document).ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        showProjects();
    });
});
```

Or even shorten this to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(showProjects());
});
```

if you know that showProjects() is the only call that you want to make.

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you just drop the word `var`

Declaring variables without `var` makes them global.

It would probably be better form to declare it before the ready block as Dan Ray suggested, but you said you had a hard time with this?  Not sure why you would.

Comment: I declare the variabel before the READY block as you have said and I give it a test value of pfb = '12/01/2010'; Then I re-declare it with the value I need from the DatePicker function... pfb = selectedDate.asString(); When I run it, I get the value 12/01/2010 rather than the date I am seeing if I set an ALERT right after the pfb = selectedDate.asString(); - which is 12/15/2010

Comment: by re-declare, the second time within ready block, do you use the word var or not?

Comment: also, not that this scoping issue isnt significant, but you can sidestep all of this by returning the value

Comment: I do not use the word VAR when I re-declare

Comment: @user That is not called a re-declaration, it's a simple assignment. Declaration: `var foo = 1;`. Assignment: `foo = 2;`

Comment: Ok gents - you are smart and I am not so... It turns out the DatePicker script wasn't being fired. Once I fired it, the new value was successfully entered into my script. Sorry - wish you could have been watching over my shoulder - you would have caught it right away I'm sure!

Comment: so downvoter - am i wrong about what happens when you omit the var?  or are you just downvoting bc you think it isnt something i should recommend? i did kind of let on that it isnt the best form